# How do I retrieve my YouTube channel playlists?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-data-api

I'm baffled. Best I can tell, I'm following the examples to the letter. Maybe I'm missing a parameter but I can't find what it is.

```
var request = gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
  id: '<myId>',
  part: 'contentDetails'
});
request.execute(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

The console response has no items, but I have 3 playlists as public.

> [Log] Object (learndataapi.html, line 68)
>
> etag: "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/Rk41fm-2TD0VG1yv0-bkUvcBi9s\""
>
> items: [] (0)
>
> kind: "youtube#channelListResponse"
>
> pageInfo: {totalResults: 0, resultsPerPage: 0}
>
> result: {kind: "youtube#channelListResponse", etag: "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/Rk41fm-2TD0VG1yv0-bkUvcBi9s\"", pageInfo: {totalResults: 0, resultsPerPage: 0}, items: []}
>
> Object Prototype

Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={your_key_here}&channelId={channel_id_here}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=30
```

Check here for more info: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Update: try these steps:

1. Use the query

   ```
   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id={channel Id}key={API key}&part=contentDetails
   ```
2. Use this "uploads" Id to query PlaylistItems to get the list of videos like:

   ```
   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?playlistId={"uploads" Id}&key={API key}&part=snippet&maxResults=50
   ```

**NEW UPDATE**

For PlayList do these :

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
   var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
   xmlHttp.send( null );
   return xmlHttp.responseText;
}

var response = httpGet("https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?channelId=UCCTVrRB5KpIiK6V2GGVsR1Q&maxResults=50&part=snippet&key=REPLACE-WITH-YOUR-API-KEY");

console.log(response);
```

So in this code, you just need to add any channel Id that you want to retrieve the playlists, in this case I retrieve from a channel with this ID : `UCCTVrRB5KpIiK6V2GGVsR1Q` if you don't know how to get the channel ID, just check the page source of any channel you want and search for this : `data-channel-external-id` and use the value for channelId Parameter.

The other thing you need is the API KEY, make sure you enabled your Youtube API data and use your API KEY for key parameter.

If you send the http request, you will get a response of details for max 50 playlits, which you have access to their Id also, something like `id:PLAC325451207E3105`

Comment: The search worked to a point. It brought back the first playlist and all my public videos. It didn't retrieve the other two playlists.

I played with the gapi.client.youtube.channels.list and realized that "id" refers to the channel id, not my id, but I still don't understand why it isn't returning an array of all the playlists on my channel. I'm missing something important.

Comment: You will receive a JSON with video ids and details. You can play with Results=30 to get more results, I think it can return up to 50 videos.

Comment: Read this page : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list you can use pageToken to get more result

Comment: I think I'm using the wrong api. Channels doesn't return what I thought it did. Will try playing around with search.

Thanks for the clue.

Comment: I'm getting nowhere. All I want to do is retrieve a list of playlists ids on my channel. I don't need the video ids in the playlist. I've tried channels.list, but that doesn't bring the right items back. In the search code above that I thought worked, I found it was taking "type: 'playlist,'" and treating playlist as a variable (which I had elsewhere) rather than a literal. When I removed the variable from my code, the search returned no pageinfo at all.

Addendum: If I leave "type" off, it brings back videos but not playlists.

Answer (score 1):

Well, finally! I've been through so many alternatives, I'm not sure why it wasn't this simple before. Guess I over-read something or another. Thanks to Emad for giving me the XMLHttpRequest from which I could build the gapi request.

```
  gapi.client.setApiKey(
    apiKey
  );

  gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3').then(function (){
    gapi.client.youtube.playlists.list ({
      channelId: '<channelId>',
      maxResults: 50,
      part: 'snippet'
    }).then (function(response){
      console.log(response.result);
      },function(reason){
        console.log(reason);
      });
  });
```

Giving a response.result:

```
[Log] Object (learndataapi.html, line 45)
      etag: "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/Ax2NdOn2dk1o3kSplGj29Msov8Q\""
      items: Array (2)
      0 Object
         etag: "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/qQMRAPjZkOKU3LcNUxjcSiBXu8k\""
         id: "<playListId>"
         kind: "youtube#playlist"
         snippet: Object
           channelId: "<channelId>"
           channelTitle: "<channelTitle>"
           description: "<channelDescription>"
           localized: {title: "New playlist 2 with 2 videos", description: "This is new playlist 2 with 2 videos"}
           publishedAt: "2017-05-08T22:47:16.000Z"
           thumbnails: {default: {url: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GsNawgbVt18/default.jpg", width: 120, height: 90}, medium: {url: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GsNawgbVt18/mqdefault.jpg", width: 320, height: 180}, high: {url: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GsNawgbVt18/hqdefault.jpg", width: 480, height: 360}}
           title: "New playlist 2 with 2 videos"

...
```

One thing of note: The playlist is always returned in descending "publishedAt" date, so latest publications are always first... if anyone cares.